# ItemsControl within WrapPanel vs ListBox within WrapPanel

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, listbox, itemscontrol

Background: I have a WrapPanel with Vertical Orientation that I want to put up to 40 "items" in. Each "item" within the WrapPanel will contain a combination of buttons and expandable lists in a 5x6 grid format. I need to be able to select each "item" within the WrapPanel so it brings up a dialogue box where the user can click the buttons and edit the expandable lists for that "item".

Question: I understand that the main difference between ItemsControl and ListBox is that the entities inside a ListBox are selectable while the ones in ItemsControl are not, however I do not need to select values inside my ItemsControl or ListBox until my dialogue appears, so I'm not sure if it would be best to use the ItemsControl or ListBox in this situation. Which ListControl would be best for my situation?

Answer (score 0):

If your root items should be selectable you would probably want a `ListBox` whose [`ItemsPanel`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.itemscontrol.itemspanel(v=vs.110).aspx) is a `WrapPanel`. If you don't need actual selection (i.e. it does not matter that items automatically deselect, or that operations are executed on the set of selected items) you can just use an `ItemsControl` with a `WrapPanel` as `ItemsPanel` and use a big `Button` as the root of your `ItemTemplate` (to trigger the dialog).

Comment: That makes it clearer. I will be using an ItemsControl with a WrapPanel as the ItemsPanel and big Buttons. Thank you!